# Submit POST data from controller to another website in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, request, form-submit

1. User submits a form with some basic data.
2. The data is received and treated by an action in the controller and more information that needs to remain private is added.
3. Then I need to send a post request to an external website with all of the combined data from the controller.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The simpliest way is using ruby core library:

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

params = {'box1' => 'Nothing is less important than which fork you use. Etiquette is the science of living. It embraces everything. It is ethics. It is honor. -Emily Post',
'button1' => 'Submit'
}
x = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://www.interlacken.com/webdbdev/ch05/formpost.asp'), params)
puts x.body
```

Pro Tip: Do an asynchronous request, using a gem like [delayed_job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/tree/master) or background_rb

Comment: An example on using delayed_job on Ryan's railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job

Comment: This was the first thing I attempted.  Unfortunately it gives me an 'end of file reached' error. From searching around it seems that others have had similar problems.  Anyone have any insights?

Comment: To solve EOF error when using https, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227933/1161743

Comment: @VladZloteanu - why is your advice "do an asyncronius request, using a gem like delayed_job" ? thanks

Answer (score 34):

Sorry, I neglected to mention that I was connecting to secure server.  This seems to have been the reason that I was getting end of file errors.  Adding using 'net/https' and calling use_ssl on connection solved the problem.  Thanks for everyones help.

```
require 'net/https'
require 'open-uri'

url = URI.parse('https://MY_URL')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.form_data = data
req.basic_auth url.user, url.password if url.user
con = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
con.use_ssl = true
con.start {|http| http.request(req)}
```

This is based off the source for the post_form method, so i guess I'll give vlad.zloteanu the answer.

Comment: :) well.. 10qu, i'm glad it helped you.

Comment: This seems to be working great, however I was expecting the controller to follow the redirection to the post as well, but it does not seems to be the case? Any any idea how I could do that?

Comment: Something I just worked out... setting the last line to response `res = con.start {|http| http.request(req)}` is useful.

Answer (score 13):

If the external server is RESTful, then simply create an [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.1/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) model to handle your data.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think redirect_to handles post requests because it uses http 302 (?) which just GETs the other page.

I believe you can do something like this

```
Class MyController < ActionController
    require 'net/http'

    def my_method
        #do something with the data/model

        my_connection = Net::HTTP.new('www.target.com', 80)
        reponse = my_connection.post(path_within_url, data)

        #do something with response if you want
    end

end
```

note: this is air coded and has not been tried or tested

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send JSON, all you need is something like the following (tested in Rails 6):

```rb
Net::HTTP.post(
  URI('https://example.com/some/path'),
  { "this is the": "request body" }.to_json,
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
)
```