# EOF with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, exception, nokogiri, eof

I have the following line in a long loop

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(topic[:url].first)).xpath('//ul[@class = "pages"]//li').first
```

Sometimes my Ruby application crashes raising the "End of file reached " exception in this line.

How can I resolve this problem? Just a begin;raise;end block?

Is a script that performs a forum backup, so is important that doesn't skip any thread.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Phrogz's excellent advice (in particular about `at_css` with the simpler expression), I would pull the raw xml [content] separately:

```
page = if (content = open(topic[:url].first)).strip.length > 0
  Nokogiri::HTML(content).xpath('//ul[@class = "pages"]//li').first
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies but I do
`next unless topic[:url].first.page_exists? '//ul[@class = "pages"]//li'`
first to do
`page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(topic[:url].first)).xpath('//ul[@class = "pages"]//li').first`.
#page_exists is a method of String:
`begin
   !Nokogiri::HTML(open(self)).to_s.empty?
rescue Exception => e
   false
end`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should first to fix the underlying issue so that you do not get this error.

- Does the same URL always cause the problem? (Output it in your log files.) If so, perhaps you need to [URI encode the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814611/405017).
- Is it random, and therefor likely related to a connection hiccup or server problem? If so, you should rescue the specific error and then [`retry`](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/tut_exceptions.html#playitagain) one or more times to get the crucial data.

Secondarily, you should know that the CSS syntax for that query is far simpler:

```
page = Nokogiri.HTML(...).at_css('ul.pages li')
```

- Not only is this less than half the bytes, it allows for cases like `<ul class="foo pages">` that the XPath would miss.
- Using [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) (or [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath)) is the same as `.css(...).first`, but is faster and simpler.

Comment: Surely can be a restriction of the server (the application is crashed with the call #458), but I cannot be sure that it is the truth...