# Capture HTTP call response using Chef

Tags: ruby, post, https, chef-infra

I'm currently using Chef to build out a cookbook that has to fire off a bunch of POST calls to this API and I have to capture the response in a variable to use it in a second HTTP call.

I've tried using the http_request resource from Ruby but I can only fire the call but don't know how to get the response captured:

```
http_request 'authorize' do   
action :post   
url '*****************************'   headers ({
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
        })   message ({
        :Username => "**********",
        :Password => "**********"
        }).to_json  
end
```

In another attempt, I tried using Chef's http client to fire off a POST call and a get a response:

```
  require "net/https"
  require "uri"
  require "json"
  uri = URI("******************************")
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
  req.set_form_data("Username" => "********", "Password" => "*********")

  res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
    http.request(req)
  end

  case res
  when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
    # OK
  else
    res.value
  end
```

But I keep getting this error when I run the chef-client on my node:

```
EOFError
--------
end of file reached
```

How can I send off a POST call using Chef/Ruby and capture its response?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @inquisitive No not yet

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `Chef::HTTP` client class, see https://coderanger.net/chef-tips/#4 for an example.

Comment: Hi, would you be able to provide a more specific example on how to capture the response back?  The response of my call returns two objects, APIKey, and ValidUntil, and I need to capture the APIKey value.

my_id =  Chef::HTTP.new('https://cmdb/').post('/')

Would using this mean my_id will equal the response returned by my post call?

Comment: Yep, you get back a string which is the body of the response.

Comment: So i got the call to work and I get back the response as a text.  Do you know how to get it back as an array so that I can parse out only ONE value in the response?  For example if the response is { A: asdasda, B: asdasdasd} I'm only interested in getting the A value out

Comment: GOT IT!!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410682/parsing-a-json-string-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

In my case the request url had https so I had to add this line and it was working.

```
http.use_ssl = true
```

If you want a more generic approach that can handle both http and https see this answer -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227933/6226283