# Resque job not able to put external requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I'm using Resque/redis on heroku to send emails as a background job. Once I run manually `Resque.enqueue(EmailSender::Email, 'send_welcome_email',345673)`on rails console, I got EOFError: end of file reached and when I dig into the stack trace I found out that the issue starts once the job calls

```
response = put(url,
    :body => {
      :id => message_id,
      :defaultAttributes => default_attributes,
      :recipients => [{
        :emailAddress => email
      }]
    }.to_json,
    :headers => {
      "Content-Type" => 'application/json',
      "Authorization" => "Bearer #{authorization['access_token']}",
    })

url = "https://api.harmony.epsilon.com/v2/messages/#{message_id}/send"
```

I run the request with Postman and it is working fine.

It is a weird problem and I am curious to understand why this issue is happening only when I called Resque but when I run the method itself on rails console, everything is working properly.

[Exception stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdU33.png)

Any help would be appreciate!

Comment: Can you provide more information? The resque job source would be helpful as well as knowing what library you're using to make the `put` request. If you're using `Net::HTTP` and the URL is using `https` it could be as simple as https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227933/85125 - hard to say without more information.

Comment: @BartJedrocha I provided more information as you requested

Comment: I am using HTTParty Post and Put requests

Comment: I  fixed this issue by adding  HTTParty library in Post and Put requests (HTTParty.Post ())