# Rails: how to simulate a form submission from inside a controller method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project where we want to automate some form submissions. How do we simulate posting a form from inside a controller method?

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the POST below to use net/http to do a form post to an external or internal HTTP end point.

[Submitting POST data from the controller in rails to another website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195962/submitting-post-data-from-the-controller-in-rails-to-another-website)

or you could use a popular HTTP client or REST client like httparty, wrest, mechanize etc. Look at the list here. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/rest-client

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing a POST to another controller within the same app (it's a large legacy app. don't want to change the other controller method).  I'm getting a 401 back even though I'm passing in an authenticity_token, any ideas?

Comment: Log the request that your are making from the Controller. Make the exact same request using a REST/HTTP Client like Postman from chrome and see that the response. I think it might fail and tell you clearly the reason for the failure. 

I cant think why your request to the same domain would fail if it is valid and authenticated. Of course you could also try other approaches actually authenticating again and not using the token just to determine what might be going wrong.