# Submitting a POST request from a rails controller to another site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post

There is an exact duplicate of this question that is over four years old [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195962/submitting-post-data-from-the-controller-in-rails-to-another-website)

Given that it's been so long, my question now is, is that answer still accurate? Is there a better way to do this now?

Comment: This is still accurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do something like this. Write a function in your controller like this:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
class custom_class
def get_api_call(args_hash)
    uri = URI.parse("sample_api_url")
    uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(what_args_you_want_to_send)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
    http.request(request).body
end

private

def what_args_you_want_to_send
{
      "varname1" => var1,
      "varname2" => var2,
      "varname3" => var3,
      "varname4" => var4
}
end
```

The result of that function will have the answer from the server you are send a request to

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. I'm guessing that setting verify_mode to VERIFY_NONE just makes it so that the request doesn't check to see who signed the site's ssl certificate?

Comment: Sets the flags for server the certification verification at beginning of SSL/TLS session. I found this here(http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).