# Submit form directly from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have simple paypal form to submit and make a payment inside in paypal. Once I saved user data, I want to initiate form submit action.

Here is a half solution - it posts data, but doesn't bring user on paypal checkout window as html form would do.
[Submitting POST data from the controller in rails to another website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195962/submitting-post-data-from-the-controller-in-rails-to-another-website)

HTML form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="return" value="http://back">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
...
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

So I need initiate submit button click from the controller with taking user to the same page where data has been posted, same as HTML form basically does.

Comment: Is your value for 'return' actually `"http://back"`? If so you probably need to make it an actual end-point in your application - like `www.yourapp.com/payment_succeeded` or whatever.

Comment: @omnikron thanks for your comment. Nope, it is only for this example. This form works well as html, but I don't know how to submit it from the controller.

Comment: Are you getting a response from paypal, with a token or similar? If I understand your case correctly, I would probably wait for this response and then redirect the user explicitly in your controller with `redirect_to <paypal url based on token in response>` - does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a link to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985596/redirect-to-using-post-in-rails). To be short - you can't make a redirect + POST request in HTTP.