# Rails - gem for downloading files from another website

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a Rails app.
I want to go to a website(http://alt19.com/) and select a set of options, then click a button which triggers the download of a CSV file. Then I want to take the file and parse it.

I have found a gem for parsing CSV files.
However, I don't know if there is a gem for navigating to another website, selecting a set of options, downloading several files and saving them somewhere where my app can process them.

Is there anything like this?
If not, are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: Checkout mechanize gem : http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Download.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mechanize gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) to scrap the page. Mechanize uses `nokogiri` as one of the dependency which is responsible for scraping and mechanize has added feature of clicking elements from the page.

Comment: It seems that the build is failing. How could I get around this?

Comment: Please elaborate. Debugging may help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the CSV Generator from makes a post with some params.
Just do the same with 'net/https' and 'open_uri'

Example :

```
require "uri"
require "net/http"

params = {'box1' => 'Nothing is less important than which fork you use. Etiquette is the science of living. It embraces everything. It is ethics. It is honor. -Emily Post',
'button1' => 'Submit'
}
x =         Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse('http://www.interlacken.com/webdbdev/ch05/formpost.asp'), params)
puts x.body
```

Example source: [Submitting POST data from the controller in rails to another website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195962/submitting-post-data-from-the-controller-in-rails-to-another-website)