# Using Rails to automatically enter username and password on a third party site

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have access to an ASP.Net site, secured behind a simple username and password authentication, that I'd like my rails app to access and display the contents.

How do I tell my rails app enter the Username, Password and then Submit?

The input elements in question are shown below...

Username:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtUserName" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUserName">
```

Password:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtPassword" type="password" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword">
```

Submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogIn" value="Log In" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogIn&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogIn">
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195962/submitting-post-data-from-the-controller-in-rails-to-another-website

Comment: Thank you MrYoshiji for pointing me in the right direction. I will definitely give this a try. I wasn't quite sure where to begin researching this out. Big help!